# rendering multiple partials after issue description in redmine plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redmine, redmine-plugins

How to render multiple partials after issue show description below is my code in hooks.rb

```
render_on :view_issues_show_description_bottom, partial: 'issues/my_description'
render_on :view_issues_show_description_bottom, partial: 'issues/my_second_description'
```

while rendering it is displaying the my_second_description page but not my_description page. Can anyone help me out of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using below code

```
render_on :view_issues_show_details_bottom,
    {:partial => "show_more_data"},
    {:partial => "show_even_more_data"}
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/redmine/redmine/Redmine/Hook/ViewListener#render_on-class_method